# Cannot find type 'Client' in scope

Tags: swift, xcode, neo4j

When following the neo4j documentation - https://neo4j.com/developer/swift/

I get the following error on step two.

> Cannot find type 'Client' in scope.

```
import Foundation
import Theo

class Neo4jService {
    
    
let theo: Client = Client(baseURL: "hostname.com", user: "username", pass: "password") 
//    With the instance hostname, username and password filled out.

}
```

I can confirm I have added Theo as a package dependency.

Tried removing and readding the package. tried cleaning and rebuilding the project. Xcode just doesnt seem to want to pick up the new module for some reason, unless im messing up adding the package dependency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation doesn’t seem to be up to date and links to an old swift library.

Make sure you use the new one at https://github.com/Neo4j-Swift/Neo4j-Swift

And the class you are trying to use seems to have been renamed to BoltClient in the new version.

Comment: Thanks Joakim. I updated the question to reflect the correct errors im getting now.